# How to save/read cookie information about randmly opened page in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, random

I have An android native app made with HTML and PhoneGap. I have a start page with one button and 10 another pages. when I press the button on the start page, randomly opens one of my 10 pages. Now I want to save a cookie that has an information about what page was randomly opened and when i on the same day press the button on my start page it navigates me again to that one of 10 pages that was randomly chosesn earlier this day. How do I do that?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can not handle cookies with html. I suggest using php and then something like this:

```
setcookie("cookie_name", "cookie_value", time()+3600*24*30);
```

This sets a cookie for 30 days. It can be accessed like this:

```
print($_COOKIE['cookie_name']);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is it also possible with Javacsript?